# Woocommerce order-view page in my account show 404 not found

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

After place order to purchased and return to order page in my account. After click on action to view detail (go to order-view) My website show 404 That page can’t be found.

Then I check on URL it show `/order-view/[order id]` not after `/my-account/`

When I manual change URL to `/my-account/order-view/[order id]` It work I can see order detail.

How to fix view button on action column to go on the correct URL?
and On the order id URL on Order column too. It goes wrong URL.

I tried to change theme one, Reactivate all plugin, Resave on permalink setting. Not work at all.

Comment: Have you done any other customization? Everything updated? This should just work. 

Maybe try to:
* use a standard theme, i.e. Storefront
* Disable one plugin after another and check if it works then. Maybe related to some plugin.

Comment: Try to flush rewrite rules by going to Admin > settings > Permalinks, then save, it could work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the default woocommerce endpoint is 'https://YOURURL/my-account/view-order/ORDER-NUMBER'

That's slightly different from the 'order-view' url you're using